# Express compatible JSON Web Token authentication middleware

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, typescript, express.js

I am writing an Express.js middleware function in a TypeScript NodeJS project that uses a function from a third-party module to perform a small workload. When writing unit tests, I want to mock this third-party function. In the following code, the `decodeFunction` parameter is what I used as a seam to inject the dependency (or, when writing unit tests, a mock). Here it is:

```
/**
 * Returns a middleware function that performs authentication using a JSON Web
 * Token (JWT).
 *
 * @remarks
 * This middleware is intended to be used during test mode only and should not
 * be considered secure.
 *
 * @param - decodeFunction - A function that decodes a JWT. *
 * @returns An Express-compatible middleware function that authenticates a JWT.
 */
export function getJwtAuthMiddleware(
    decodeFunction: DecodeFunction = decode
): (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void> {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        const { authorization } = req.headers || "";

        if (!authorization) {
            next(new HttpException(401, "An authorization header is required."));
            return;
        }

        const [authType, token] = authorization.trim().split(" ");

        if (authType !== "Bearer") {
            next(new HttpException(401, "The specified authentication scheme is not supported."));
            return;
        }

        try {
            const result = await decodeFunction(token, config.testModeJwtSecret, false, "HS256");
            req.user = { id: result.sub };
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(new HttpException(401, "Authorization is required.", error));
        }
    };
}
```

This seems to work just fine, but I'm relatively inexperienced with TypeScript/JavaScript and would love to hear from the community here as to whether there are alternative approaches I should consider or best practices I've ignored.